# How to trigger an INSERT function after all rows have TRUE value in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql, triggers

here is the problem. I am working on a website which will help people share chapters of a book. The book has 30 chapters and after every chapter is marked as read, I want my database to create next sets of chapters in the chapters table. I don't know if this is an efficient way to do it or should I use PHP if conditions.

Here is my chapters table:

```
CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `chapter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chapter_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `completion_cycle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

When all the read values of 30 chapters for first completion cycle is TRUE (or equal to 1), I want my MySQL to add 30 more rows to chapters table with a new completion cycle id. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: when a user_id has marked read a row (assuming all 30 were first inserted as not read to start for that user) ... but in the After Update trigger you could do it.

Comment: Yes but my condition is that all chapters should have value of TRUE for read column, i don't know how to check all 30 rows in a TRIGGER statement

Comment: The trigger has `NEW.` . That can be used directly or manipulated into DECLARE variables and a select count from there. The update trigger is not allowed to insert a row in the same table. So a separate sentinel table is needed to clue in an Event that would process it. The Event runs on a schedule that you decide. Say, every n minutes. This would be the same as `cron` but it avoids using cron.

Answer (score 0):

First, create the table

```
CREATE TABLE `chapters` (
  `chapter_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `chapter_no` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `completion_cycle` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `read` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

In your PHP or in a cron job you can now check if the chapters are completed by using:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM chapters
WHERE completion_cycle=0
AND read=0;
```

If the above query returns 0 results, that means all chapters are completed and read. So you can insert the next one.

```
INSERT INTO chapters (chapter_no, completion_cycle, user_id, read)
VALUES
('...', 0, '...', 0);
```

The next chapter is now inserted

Comment: That should help! Thank you!!

Comment: Your first select stmt up there has to take into account the info about the book and userid and all that jazz.